# DRY jasmine tests - share code between multiple .js files

Tags: javascript, jasmine

**TLDR**: Is it possible to share code between two .js files?

Situation:

I set up an `angular` app using the `yeoman` command `yo angular`

I have the following directory layout for my karma jasmine tests:

```
../client/test/spec
.... /controllers
........ * jasmine tests *
.... /directives
........ * jasmine tests *
.... /services
........ * jasmine tests *
```

for example I have two tests:

```
userservice.js
navservice.js
```

Within each **.js** file i'm able to be **DRY** by sharing `describe` functions etc however is it possible to share some code between the **.js** files themselves? For example I could share this [using](http://blog.jphpsf.com/2012/08/30/drying-up-your-javascript-jasmine-tests) function rather than cut and pasting it into each file.

Coming from python I would generally make a  file `common.py` and in my other test case files I would have `from common import sharedFunction` to make use of the `sharedFunction`

edit: this is the command I use to run tests:

```
/usr/local/bin/node "/Users/robertking/Library/Application Support/PyCharm30/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijRunner.js" --karmaPackageDir=/Users/../client/node_modules/karma --serverPort=8080 --urlRoot=/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have `node` you can create JavaScript file with helpers methods and **[require](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)** it in tests.

Second solution - **Karma** can load any JavaScript files – not only development and tests files but also … helpers. Please take a look into karma.conf.js file and section `files: []`

Answer (score 0):

I went with **Krzysztof Safjanowski's** solution. It turns out I already had `'test/spec/**/*.js'` in my `karma.conf.js` which meant I could just put `common.js` in my `test/spec` folder. Only thing to be careful of is isolation & race conditions etc since the tests are run in parallel:

```
files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-scroll/angular-scroll.min.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-gapi/modules/gapi-client.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-gettext/dist/angular-gettext.js',
      'app/bower_components//ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
      'app/scripts/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      //'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
```